# mongo_client TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pycharm

I wrote the below code in Pycharm.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import mongo_client
connection = mongo_client()
```

When I executed the code, I got the below error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Mohan/PycharmProjects/pymongo/mongotutorial.py", line 7, in
>   
>       connection = mongo_client()
>   TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.

My Python version is 3.6.5. Can you please help?

Comment: Did you install pymongo? You can install the module with `pip install pymongo`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code below:

```python
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['test-database'] # or db = client.test_database
collection = db['test-collection'] # or collection = db.test_collection
```

Hope it helps.